# How to list tags being used by a specific user with ActsAsTaggableOn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I am building something similar to a personal journaling application using the Devise and ActsAsTaggableOn ruby gems.

In a nutshell, each user has a private profile to create a database of their own personal journals (this is where I used devise)

I wanted to implement the ability for the user to hashtag journals so they can easily sort and find specific journals in their database, including the top three hashtags being used in the specific user’s database of journals.

I successfully added the tags to each specific journal using the ActsAsTaggableOn gem. However, I am having trouble understanding the documentation for finding the journal tags specific to the user’s profile and consequently the top three hashtags being used in the user’s journals database.

I basically need `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.most_used` to filter only for the journals on a user’s profile.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT - code below

Here is my user model…

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :journals, dependent: :destroy
  validates_presence_of :fname, :lname
  acts_as_tagger
end
```

Here is my journal model..

```
class Journal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :title, :body
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

On my show page when I use `<%= current_user.owned_tags.most_used(3) %>` on my user profile page, the following displays: 
`#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x00007ffb28123ce0>`

Comment: Please, add corresponding code of User and Journal models

Answer (score 0):

You need to add owner to tags.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tagger
end
```

Note, in this case you can't use `tag_list` anymore, because it stores only unowned tags.

```
current_user.tag(@journal, with: "Cars") # to add owned tag to the journal
@journal.tags_from(current_user) # to fetch journal tags
```

Now you can get most used tags for the user

```
current_user.owned_tags.most_used(3)
```

Another option (without ownership):

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.joins(:taggable).where(taggable: current_user.journals)
  .distinct.most_used(3)
```

In any case you have ActiveRecord relation as a result. To display it in the view you should iterate it.

```
<% most_used_tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= tag.name %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= most_used_tags.map(&:name).join(', ') %>
```

Comment: thanks! i updated my models, but still have trouble displaying the tags...i included the models above - thanks so much!

Comment: @JeffMonteiro I updated the answer, check it please